# catkin_make error: invoking "cmake" failed

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm on ubuntu 14.04
I'm using ROS indigo.
I am new to ROS.
I know there are similar questions on here but their answers didn't help me.

I've been following some ROS/catkin tutorials and am currently on this one: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace.

The instructions all worked fine until I got to catkin_make.
Roscore was running in a separate terminal at the time.

I took a snapshot of the error and was going to upload it but apparently I don't have enough points.
(If you want to teach newbies to write questions in an easy-to-follow way, it'd be useful to allow them to upload screenshots.)

I uploaded the screenshot to photobucket instead:

[image description http://i1188.photobucket.com/albums/z410/Tomatoes1/Screenshot%20from%202016-03-19%20184600.png](http://i1188.photobucket.com/albums/z410/Tomatoes1/Screenshot%20from%202016-03-19%20184600.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229563/catkin_make-error:-invoking-%22cmake%22-failed/) by [Fuzzball](https://answers.ros.org/users/26330/fuzzball/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-19**:\

> [..] it'd be useful to allow them to upload screenshots.

Personally I'd rather ppl copy/paste the console *text*, as it is then indexed by search engines, whereas images are not. Also: img hosts have different retention policies, which can lead to screenshots disappearing.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-19**:\

> I'm on windows 8.1 [..]

Can you please tell us how you installed ROS, which VM product you are using and what arch this is?

**Comment by [Fuzzball](https://answers.ros.org/users/26330/fuzzball/) on 2016-03-19**:
I'm not sure what a VM product is or what an arch is. I just realized that windows 8.1 was incorrect (I got confused cos this computer has two operating systems), I'm using ROS on Ubuntu 14.04. I installed ROS by following the steps in this link: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-19**:
VM == virtual machine, arch == processor architecture. As you reported you were *running Windows 8.1*, the only way to have ROS running would be in a virtual machine, hence my question.

**Comment by [ross123](https://answers.ros.org/users/27191/ross123/) on 2016-06-16**:
Hi.I have met the same situation. Have you solved it yet? Thanks for your help.

**Comment by [tobinfinity](https://answers.ros.org/users/30658/tobinfinity/) on 2017-06-06**:
hi, found the answer http://answers.ros.org/question/196915/invoking-cmake-failed/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

try:

> $ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

to see a list of paths, you should see something like:

> /opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks

If not, probably you have placed a new path to your `~/.bashrc` . Simply remove it and it should work.

Type:

> $ sudo gedit ~/.bashrc

a file will open, scroll all the way down and remove the last one(s), save and exit. Try in a new terminal.

---

Originally posted by [Rai](https://answers.ros.org/users/29580/rai/) with karma: 30 on 2017-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0